# NASM - Compare two numbers

Tags: gcc, assembly, nasm, x86-64

```
global  main        ; define for linker
extern  printf      ; tell linker we need this C function
        section .data       ; Data section, initialized variables
    a:  dq 3
    b:  dq 2

    fmt0:   db "True"
    fmt1:   db "Equal"
    fmt2:   db "False"

    section .text
main:   push rbp
    mov rax,[a]
    cmp rax,[b]
    jg  true
    je  equal
    jmp less

exit:
    pop rbp
    mov rax,0
    ret 

true:
    mov rdi, fmt0
    call    printf
    jmp exit

equal:  
    mov rdi, fmt1
    call    printf
    jmp exit

less:   
    mov rdi, fmt2
    call    printf
    jmp exit
```

Could someone tell me, Why It's working for a = 1 b = 2 but If a is bigger then all the functions are called and returned is "TrueEqualFalse", I am newbie in assembler and I want to know what's wrong with this code

Comment: `printf` expects a null-terminated string. Add a null to the strings, Also, add a `xor eax,eax` before every `printf` (calling convention for 64-bit Linux).

Comment: Oh, I see. But Could you explain me why we need to do like 'fmt0:   db "True", 0'? It's like end of string? Thanks for help.

Comment: Exactly. `printf` prints until it reaches a 0.